# Simplifying an inequality inside an answer by parts

Tags: simplifying-expressions, inequalities

I have the following piece of code where I'm evaluating a probability of a variable `v` being greater than some threshold under a Uniform distribution.

```
assum := aL > bL && aL >= bL + T && aL + T < \[Delta] && bL - T > -\[Delta] && T > 0 && \[Delta] > 0 && 0 < pS < 1
FullSimplify[ Probability[0 < pS < 1 && v > (-aL + bL pS + pS T)/(-1 + pS), v \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-\[Delta], \[Delta]}]], assum]
```

The output I get is an answer with three parts. The condition for the second part is

```
(aL >= pS (bL + T) || pS (bL + T + \[Delta]) < aL + \[Delta]) && (aL < pS (bL + T) || pS (bL + T - \[Delta]) + \[Delta] > aL)
```

which should evaluate to True given the assumptions (and the condition for the first part should evaluate to False).

Is there a way I can have Mathematica evaluate those conditions to True or False to further simplify the answer, and thus only get one answer, without explicitly stating that the condition is True?

Comment: Why do you have `0 < pS < 1` inside the call to `Probability`? When I remove this I find that the condition giving 1 is True.